# easy way to draw a Tree Graph with python from classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, tree

I'm looking for an easy way to create a tree in Python from classes.

Examples of the classes I have:

```
class ChanceNode:
    def __init__(self, *, name, children):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

class RootNode:
    def __init__(self, *, name, children):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

etc...
```

How can I draw (=vizualize in .jpg or equivalent) a simple tree from a few defined classes such as this?

Comment: This is primarily opinon based. There are many tools like matplotlib,turtle graphics etc. So pick your poison.

Comment: Im looking for the easiest and fastest way to do it